# Updating a Constraint Multiple Times

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

In my Swift app, I need to update an AutoLayout constraint multiple times, so I have a function which does this. I'm having an issue with this constraint not being updated sometimes, and I've narrowed down the issue to being that it updates the first time the function is called, but not if that function is called again.

The code from the function looks like this:

```
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.prompt, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([verticalSpace])
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Is there something which needs to be done in order to update a function multiple times?

Comment: what is your actual  requirement ? do you just need to update the top-constraint  value  from 10 to anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have "competing" constraints. If you set the verticalSpace to 10, then set *another* verticalSpace to 20, which constraint should be used?

What you need to do is *remove* the existing constraint (or deactivate it), and then add/activate your new constraint.

Or...

Create your verticalConstraint and save a reference to it... then when you want to change it you can change the `.constant` however you wish.

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't thought of the conflicting constraints. The second option worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.prompt, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([verticalSpace])
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still having the same issue where it will update the first time, but not afterwards.

Comment: @Toby What is the result of this? Is the object you're setting the constraint to begin animated or something? Usually a constraint would only need to be updated once.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I've just achieved this by the following rule.

*Either*

> **Step 1:**
>
> remove that constraint which you want to update.
>
> **Step 2:**
>
> Add constraint again.

*or*

> Update constraint value.

In both cases you should have the reference of that constraint which you want to update.

**How:**

I have just added my demo code.I have programmatically added a view and and changed it's vertical constraint by button click.Just go through the code.

Upto viewDidLoad method:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let someView = UIView()
    var topValue:CGFloat = 10
    var verticalConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //This below codes are used to add a red color UIView in center which has width and height both 100
        someView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(someView)
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) //Center horizontally
        verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: topValue) // center vertically.want to change that constraint later so took a variable.
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100) //width 100
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100) //height 100
        view.addConstraints([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])

    }
```

And for each button click topConstant will be gradually updated.

This is the code for **Either** part which i mentioned.

```
self.view.removeConstraint(verticalConstraint)
verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: 
NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: 
view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 
topValue)
self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
```

And this is the code for **or** part.

```
verticalConstraint.constant = topValue
```

And my buttonClick event method is basically like this.

```
@IBAction func updateView(_ sender: Any) {
    topValue += 10
    //In this case I've removed the previous constraint and add that constraint again with new Value
    self.view.removeConstraint(verticalConstraint)
     verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: someView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: topValue)
    self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)

    //In this case I've just update that constraint value.Commented because we are using first method
    //verticalConstraint.constant = topValue

}
```

And my output.
[image]